# Creating Media Service Credentials

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I'm trying to set up the Azure Media Service. I created the media service from Azure but I don't know where can obtain the account key.

> client = new CloudMediaContext(new MediaServicesCredentials(accountName, accountKey));

I'm following this tutorial: [Integrating applications with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications)

But after get the secret key in step 4 in "*To add application credentials, or permissions to access web APIs*" doesn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> client = new CloudMediaContext(new MediaServicesCredentials(accountName, accountKey));

Azure Media Services announces support for AAD and **deprecation of ACS authentication**.

> Because Azure Active Directory provides powerful role-based access control features and support for more fine-grained access to resources in your account compared to the ACS token authentication model ("account keys"), **we strongly recommend that you update your code and migrate from ACS to AAD-based authentication by June 22, 2018**.
>
> Also, a key reason for the rapid migration is the upcoming announced deprecation of the ACS key based authentication system.

**User Authentication with AAD in Media Services**

A native application would first acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory and then use that access token to make all REST API calls.

The following examples show how a daemon application may use AAD web application credentials to authenticate requests with the REST service.

[image]

For a REST API request to succeed, the calling user must be a **“Contributor” or “Owner”** of the Azure Media Services account it is trying to access.

Users of the .NET client SDK for Media Services must upgrade to the latest version on Nuget (**windowsazure.mediaservices version 4.1.0.1 or greater**) to use AAD authentication for communicating with REST requests.

You could use the following code to [connect to the Media Services account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-get-started#connect-to-the-media-services-account).

```
class Program
    {
        // Read values from the App.config file.
        private static readonly string _AADTenantDomain =
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSAADTenantDomain"];
        private static readonly string _RESTAPIEndpoint =
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSRESTAPIEndpoint"];
        private static readonly string _AMSClientId =
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSClientId"];
        private static readonly string _AMSClientSecret =
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSClientSecret"];

        private static CloudMediaContext _context = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        try
        {
            AzureAdTokenCredentials tokenCredentials = 
                new AzureAdTokenCredentials(_AADTenantDomain,
                    new AzureAdClientSymmetricKey(_AMSClientId, _AMSClientSecret),
                    AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);

            var tokenProvider = new AzureAdTokenProvider(tokenCredentials);

            _context = new CloudMediaContext(new Uri(_RESTAPIEndpoint), tokenProvider);

            // Add calls to methods defined in this section.
            // Make sure to update the file name and path to where you have your media file.
            IAsset inputAsset =
            UploadFile(@"C:\VideoFiles\BigBuckBunny.mp4", AssetCreationOptions.None);

            IAsset encodedAsset =
            EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateMP4s(inputAsset, AssetCreationOptions.None);

            PublishAssetGetURLs(encodedAsset);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Parse the XML error message in the Media Services response and create a new
            // exception with its content.
            exception = MediaServicesExceptionParser.Parse(exception);

            Console.Error.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        }
```

**NOTE**: Applications will also need to update their references to include a new assembly "`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.Common.Authentication.dll`" and add references to that namespace as well as reference to the "`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`" assembly to get access to the `ITokenProvider` interface.

Click API access and choose "

Connect to Azure Media Services API with user authentication".

[image]

This includes the API endpoint that you need to call, along with the ClientID, Domain, and Resource.

[image]

For more details about how to connect to Media Services with Azure AD, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-media-service-aad-auth-and-acs-deprecation/).

Comment: Joey, you rock! Thanks for jumping in here for us.